# How to apply `@POJO` to classes via config script?

Tags: groovy

I have a few classes which I'd like to keep as POJO. Manually annotating each of these would be troublesome, for both updating all current ones and adding future such classes.

I have a `SourceAwareCustomizer` able to identify all these classes. However I do not know how to apply the `@POJO` via the config script.

I tried `ast(POJO)`, and I would get an error:

```
Provided class doesn't look like an AST @interface
```

I dug in the code a bit and found that `@POJO` is not an AST transformation (it's not annotated with `@GroovyASTTransformationClass`.

Is there a way to apply `@POJO`, or maybe a random annotation, to a class via the config script?

Comment: What's the "config script" ? What is the problem to use annotation in it?

Comment: @daggett https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_the_configscript_commandline_parameter

Comment: "I dug in the code a bit and found that @POJO is not an AST transformation" - Is that related to your question?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes. If it was not obvious, I was assuming `POJO` to be an AST, and tried to apply it as an AST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POJO is not an AST transformation.

Compare [POJO](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/groovy/transform/stc/POJO.java#L34) source to [ToString](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/groovy/transform/ToString.java#L259) (for example). In POJO the `GroovyASTTransformationClass` annotation is missing..

I can't make @POJO working without @CompileStatic..

So, here is my try with groovy 4.0.1:

**congig.groovy**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode

import groovy.transform.stc.POJO
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

withConfig(configuration) { 
   inline(phase:'SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS'){Object...args->
     if(args.size()>2){
       ClassNode cn = args[2]
       if( cn.getSuperClass().name=="java.lang.Object" ) {
         if( !cn.annotations.find{it.classNode.name==POJO.class.name} ) {
           cn.addAnnotation( new AnnotationNode(new ClassNode(POJO.class)) )
           //can't see how POJO could work without compile static in groovy 4.0.1
           if( !cn.annotations.find{it.classNode.name==CompileStatic.class.name} )
             cn.addAnnotation( new AnnotationNode(new ClassNode(CompileStatic.class)) )
         }
       }

       println "class       = $cn"
       println "annotations = ${cn.getAnnotations()}"
     }
   }
}
```

**A.groovy**

```
class A{
    String id
}
```

compile command line:

```
groovyc --configscript config.groovy A.groovy
```

**generated class**

```
public class A
{
    private String id;
    
    @Generated
    public A() {}
    
    @Generated
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    @Generated
    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on `inline`. I did not notice `InlinedASTCustomizerFactory`. And the possible phases seem to be `CompilePhase`. Sorry I did not mentioned that I had `ast(CompileStatic)` in it already (`CompileStatic` is an AST). I was expecting a shorter version similar to `ast()`. But it seems there is no such customizer factory available out of the box.

Comment: This is interesting. 1. It seems only phases `SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS` and `CONVERSION` would make differences. (I don't have a good understanding of what these compile phases actually mean.) 2. The annotations in each phase have different names (fully qualified in `SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS`, and literal name in `CONVERSION`). 3. The `ast(CompileStatic)` I applied outside this closure is not useful in this approach. `CompileStatic` must be set together with `POJO` in this phase.

Comment: Annotation processors seem to interfere with the `SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS` phase. Without any annotation processor enabled, this could generate a POJO. But once I add any AP (I use gradle), the compiled class starts to implementing `GroovyObject`. It seems to be fine when this is done in `CONVERSION` phase. However in `CONVERSION` phase the ClassNode is only getting literal annotations used in code, and could be hard to tell the exact annotation attached.